# Column collapse at 768px, menu collapses at 767px?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My website uses [twitter-bootstrap-3](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) and has a 2 column layout (`col-sm-9` and `col-sm-3`).

`col-sm-9` contains my blog and `col-sm-3` contains a sidebar nav.

For some strange reason the nav bar collapses at `767px`, while the blog container collapses at `768px`.

This means when I have the viewport at exactly `768px`, the menu looks terrible.

Is this a bug of some sort and can someone help me resolve this?

```
<div class="col-sm-9 tutorial-panel">
  <section>
    This is my blog content 
  </section>

  <nav class="col-sm-3 navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
          data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="clearfix">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a bug

Comment: can this be resolved? thanks

Comment: Where is your whole HTML code?

Comment: Try adding `box-sizing:border-box` on target elements style.

Comment: This can f.e. happen when different elements are affected by different media queries, that approach one specific breakpoint pixel value from two sides, one using `max-width` and the other `min-width`. Create a [mcve], so we can check.

Answer (score 1):

look at the [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), you can't have the `navbar` inside a `.col-*-*`, and that it might causing the issue.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```